# Checkbox is always unchecked in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html

I have below HTML code where I click on the header check box and it should check all the check box rows

```
<thead>
            <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
              <th>
                <lightning-input type="checkbox" variant="label-hidden" label="headerCheckbox"
                  onchange={headerCheckoxChanged}>
                </lightning-input>
              </th>
</thead>
<tbody>
            <template if:true={lineItemData}>
              <template for:each={lineItemData} for:item="lineItem">
                <tr key={lineItem.lineItemId}>
                  <td>
                    <lightning-input type="checkbox" variant="label-hidden" value={lineItem.includedInAutomatedSupplies}
                      data-key={lineItem.lineItemId} label="dataCheckbox" onchange={dataChekChange}>
                    </lightning-input>
                  </td>
```

Below is the JS:

```
@track lineItemData;
    headerCheckoxChanged(event) {
            this.lineItemData.forEach(element =>{
                element.includedInAutomatedSupplies = event.target.checked;
            });
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.lineItemData));
        }
```

UI snippet:

[image]

in the console log I can see the value of all checkBox change to true false as per the header but the same doesn't apply at the UI
Please suggest what I am missing.

**Updated**
In my debugging I tried printing the value of checkbox on the screen:

```
{lineItem.includedInAutomatedSupplies}
                    <lightning-input type="checkbox" variant="label-hidden" value={lineItem.includedInAutomatedSupplies}
                      data-key={lineItem.lineItemId} label="dataCheckbox" onchange={dataChekChange}>
                    </lightning-input>
```

In case of true value is showing as true but the checkbox is still unchecked

[image]

In case of false

[image]

Even value is behaving as expected but it doesn't update check box as it should,

**Please confirm what I am missing something.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used `value` instead of `checked` in body checkboxes.

```
    <td>
            <lightning-input type="checkbox" variant="label-hidden" 
                  checked={lineItem.includedInAutomatedSupplies}
                  data-key={lineItem.lineItemId} label="dataCheckbox" onchange={dataChekChange}>
            </lightning-input>
    </td>
```

---

### Improvement:

It is better to use javascript function [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of `forEach` because ***forEach*** modifies existing array and ***map*** will return new array.

```
headerCheckoxChanged(event) {
    this.lineItemData = this.lineItemData.map(element => {
        element.includedInAutomatedSupplies = event.target.checked;
        return element;
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.lineItemData));
}
```

Comment: You are a genius and I am an idiot.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help